# GraphApi API error codes

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to create a interface between our web application and the GraphApi.
I am currently struggling to handle error correctly as the documentation for graph API seems to be at best incomplete.  Is there a reference to full list of errors one should expect.

An example of the issue is where I make a request after my access token has expired.  The error code is not on the list (graph.microsoft.io docs/overview/errors page) and in a different format (capitalization).  It also seems to vary drastically from the azure error codes such as "Request_BadRequest". This was found in an MSDN article titled "Error codes and error handling | Graph API concepts".

The document states "You may use the information returned here instead of, or in addition to the HTTP status code returned.".  However, this is really hard if they are changing despite being out of beta.

example of an error response body:

```
{ "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token has expired.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "267438d2-4cc5-4621-9307-2af26d2f5b49",
      "date": "2016-02-16T13:30:24"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: some more testing has shown that if I form an invalid request I get back a HTTP response of 400 Bad Request and a body error code of "invalid_request"  which does not match the "invalidRequest" stated in the documentation as well as being formatted differently.  In that error is no longer an object, but a string.

Comment: GitHub [issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/125) created.